# Solucion a problema con select en mvc php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, mvc

Buen dia todos necesito solucion a mi problema resulta que estoy realizando un sistema en PHP con MVC de usuarios y roles tengo una tabla usuarios con los campos id, nombre, apellidos, id_rol y tabla roles con id_rol, nombre.

Muestro en una pestaña la informacion de la tabla usuarios ejem: 1, daniel, ramirez, 1 mi consulta es quiero mostrar en un select la información de la tabla roles pero cuando edito que me muestre el nombre del rol lo he estado intentando pero no lo logro espero me puedan ayudar. aqui mi codigo:

**SELECT**:

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="rol" class="font-weight-bold">Rol</label>
  <select class="form-control" name="edit_rol">
    <option value="" id="edit_rol">Seleccione Rol</option>
      <?php foreach ($roles as $rol){ ?>
       <option value="<?php echo $rol["id_rol"] ?>"><?php echo $rol["nom_rol"]; ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
   </select>
 </div>
```

**MODELO**:

```
static public function mdlMostrarPersonalId($tabla,$item,$valor){
        
        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE $item = :$item");
        $stmt -> bindParam(":".$item, $valor, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $stmt -> execute();

        return $stmt->fetch();

        $stmt -> close();

        $stmt = null;


    }
```

**CONTROLADOR**:

```
static public function ctrEditarPersonal(){

        if(isset($_POST['idPer'])){

            $datos = array( "idper" => $_POST["idPer"],
                            "user" => $_POST["edit_user"],
                            "apel" => $_POST["edit_apel"],
                            "rol" => $_POST["edit_rol"]);

            
            $tabla = "usuarios";

            $respuesta = ModeloPersonal::mdlEditarPersonal($tabla,$datos);

            if ($respuesta == "ok") {
                echo '<script>

                  Swal.fire({
                    icon: "success",
                    title: "El usuario ha sido modificado correctamente!",
                    confirmButtonText: "Cerrar"
                      
                    }).then((result)=>{
                        if(result.value){
                            window.location = "index.php?pagina=usuarios"
                        }
                    
                    });
                  
                  </script>';
            }               

        }

    }
```

**AJAX**:

```
class ajaxusuarios{
    
    public $idPersonal;

    public function ajaxeditarusuarios(){

        $item = "id";
        $valor = $this->idPersonal;

        $respuesta = ControladorPersonal::ctrMostrarPersonalId($item,$valor);

         echo json_encode($respuesta);

    }
}

if (isset($_POST["idPersonal"])) {

    $editar = new ajaxusuarios();
    $editar -> idPersonal = $_POST["idPersonal"];
    $editar -> ajaxeditarusuarios();
}
```

**ARCHIVO JS**:

```
$.ajax({

    url: "ajax/usuarios.ajax.php",
    method: 'POST',
    data: datos,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(respuesta){

        //console.log("respuesta", respuesta);

        $("#edit_idPer").val(respuesta["id"]);
        $("#edit_user").val(respuesta["nombre"]);
        $("#edit_apel").val(respuesta["apellidos"]);
        $("#edit_rol").html(respuesta["rol"]);
    }
});
```

Comment: Haz un lookup en la consulta SQL, o bien concatena ese id del rol más el nombre únicamente en el SELECT html, de modo que puedas visualizarlo al momento de editar el usuario, pero en value pasas unicamente el id. Por ej: `<select><option value='5'>5 - Pepito </option> </select>`

Comment: Entiendo que tendria que agregarle a cada uno !!! o es dinamico y como lo podria hacer?? no entiendo que es lookup ???